# Switch Loop Setup

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, ceiling-fan

Owner of home tried to setup new ceiling fan did not work. Asked me to come over and fix it.

How I think it is setup:

Switch has hot wire and hot black wire. They go to light fixture. From light fixture goes to outlet.
(outlet has two black wires wire nutted together 1 neutral on hot side of outlet and 1 neutral on neutral side of outlet. homeowner unsure if they hooked neutrals back up same way. (outlet is setup as switched outlet on both plugs)

**Is it safe if neutrals are on wrong side of hot and neutral of outlet? Basically I need to know what the outlet should be wired as, should the neutral coming in with the hot be on the neutral side or the hot side of the outlet?**

(below is how I think it should be wired/ is wired? or do  need to switch neutrals in outlet box)?

[image]

**Which is correct above or below?** (regardless outlet still works with neutrals wired either way if that helps.)

[image]

****Update****
What if the switch goes to the outlet and not the fan. Black supplies power to fan and the neutral comes back and supplies power to outlet when switch is flipped. In that case which neutral should be on hot side or neutral side of outlet?

So which of these would be right?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, neither one looks right. You have a hot/neutral at the receptacle, but the hot is continuing to the light while the receptacle is connected across the neutral. What is happening at the light?

Comment: Both of your drawings put the outlet in **series** with the fan which is just wrong. They need to be in **parallel**.

Comment: White(neutral) should not be used as a hot wire, except for switch loops.  On second picture at outlet, whites should on same side with blacks connected to other(brass screw) side(or by pig tail).  At switch, white wire should be taped/painted black at both ends(switch and light/fixture).  With house wiring almost always black to black and white to white.

Comment: Might have to check that whole circuit back to panel to make sure no whites are being used for hot/live/power wire.

Comment: What if the switch goes to the outlet and not the fan. Black supplies power to fan and the neutral comes back and supplies power to outlet when switch in that case which neutral should be on hot side or neutral side of outlet?

Comment: As mentioned, the white wire in a cable used as a switch loop can be _hot_, in which case it is _not_ a neutral (although it should be marked to indicate that).  Determining which white wire is actually a neutral and which is used as a switch leg (hot) will tell you where it can be connected.

Comment: @HopefulDIYer - Is this the same question?  It appears to be the same situation.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/237468/how-do-i-fix-this-crossed-wiring-situation

Comment: I think OP was unhappy with the answer they got there.  They certainly *didn't read* my answer.  OP seems to want to work with the "spam guesses at us" format instead of simply documenting what is there. Partly, OP is not there, and doesn't know.